# Trying to redirect for an error message instead of getting undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hey I'm getting an error when users hit  the upload button and haven't chosen a file to upload. I know I just need an if else statement but not sure where to put it or if my syntax is right.
This is my controller

```
def import
@samples = Sample.all
Sample.import(params[:file])
redirect_to root_url, notice: "Samples Imported"
authorize @samples
end
```

This is in my model...

```
class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Sample.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You can check with `if params[:file].present?` in controller

Comment: OK. I have added for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `if params[:file].present?` in controller.

Answer (score 0):

If u r using Paperclip add this line to your attachment model
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

`validates_attachment_presence :attach, :message => "No file selected"`

Comment: I'm not using paper clip. Thanks for the help the above comment was correct.